# R equivalent to Stata's `compress` command?

Tags: r

Stata has a command called `compress` which looks through all the data rows and tries to coerce each to the most efficient format.  For instance, if you have a bunch of integers stored as a character vector within a data.frame, it will coerce that to integer.

I can imagine how one might write such a function in R, but does it exist already?

Comment: It would be easy to write code that would test for integer-ness and coerce if some specified fraction of values were not-NA, but I think the general answer is "no".

Comment: That was my thinking as well.  The trick would be to write efficient code so that it didn't take forever to run.  Regexes would be the obvious way to begin, but might be too slow.

Comment: If you were to test using length(levels(factor())) and convert to factor iff that value were less than 20% of hte length of the vector you might also get space savings. Likewise you could check to see what fraction of the vector, vrc, had values == trunc(vec) it might be a test for whether coercing a numeric to integer would be wise. I didn't see much applicability of regex methods myself, but perhaps I am again obtuse.

Comment: @DWin factors are always less space efficient than character strings on 32-bit platforms. They are more efficient on 64-bit platforms for smaller level ratios (due to `sizeof(SEXP) == 2 * sizeof(int)`) so the rule would vary by platform...(if you want to be pedantic ;))

Comment: stata's "compress" will not convert character data types into numeric ones. It will only optimize storage within the character and numeric data types. Lets say, a variable with numbers up to 10 will be converted from a float or double into a "byte" data type (a very convenient format that R does not support). But a character variable with 1 to 10 numbers will not be converted to numeric

Comment: @LucasMation you're correct.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically, `read.table` does exactly that with the help of `type.convert`. So you could use that - it is not the most efficient way but probably the easiest:

```
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df ,function(x) type.convert(as.character(x))))
```

In practice it may be better to do that selectively, though, so you only touch characters/factors:

```
for (i in seq.int(df)) if (is.factor(df[[i]]) || is.character(df[[i]]))
    df[[i]] <- type.convert(as.character(df[[i]]))
```